# how to get dynamic data using JSoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm  a beginner at android and I'm trying to make an app that get values from a html file hosted in a webserver that gets data from sensors of an arduino. But JSoup only gets the first value, i don't know how to get the values that changed.

Here is the MainAcivity.java code:

```
Public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
private AnimationDrawable creepyAnimation;
private ImageView creepyImage;
private TextView result;
RequestQueue requestQueue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    creepyImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.creepy);
    creepyImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);
    creepyAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) creepyImage.getBackground();
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    getWebSite();



}
private void getWebSite(){

    new  Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder  builder = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("http://munhoz-unifei.000webhostapp.com/").get();
                Element valor1 = doc.getElementById("sala");
                Element valor2 = doc.getElementById("quarto");

                builder.append(valor1.attr("sala")).append("xxx: ").append(valor1.text()).append("\n");
                builder.append(valor2.attr("quarto")).append("lalala: ").append(valor2.text()).append("\n");

               /*
                for (Element element : valor){
                    builder.append(element.attr("sala"))
                            .append("\n").append("text: ").append(element.text());


                }
               */
            }catch (IOException e){
                builder.append("ERROR: ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    result.setText(builder.toString());


                }
            });
        }
    }).start();



}
```

}

i just want to get the values to change on the app as it changes on the website. Could someone give me a hint or an example of how to do this work?

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup can only parse or process the html that is sent by the server.
Anything part of the `DOM` that is generated by the javascript on the client's end can't be parsed through `Jsoup`.

What you can try is selenium web automation to obtain the html rendered by the browser.

Comment: In the context of android using a webview is a simpler way to grab the dynamic content.